# Perl modules is not getting installed in Amazon Linux AMI ( centOs 6.5)

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, perl

I am configuring cloudwatch custom metrics which requires some perl modules to be installed.

Here is the command I am trying to install the perl modules.

```
yum install perl-Switch perl-Sys-Syslog perl-LWP-Protocol-http
```

I am running CentOs 6.5 on AWS. Here is the response I am getting.

```
    [root@ip-10-21-1-38 aws-scripts-mon]# yum install perl-Switch perl-Sys-Syslog perl-     LWP-Protocol-http
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    * base: mirror.es.its.nyu.edu
    * extras: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
    * updates: mirror.ash.fastserv.com
    Setting up Install Process
    No package perl-Switch available.
    No package perl-Sys-Syslog available.
    No package perl-LWP-Protocol-http available.
    Error: Nothing to do
    You have new mail in /var/spool/mail/root
```

Please do help with installing perl modules.

Comment: These packages are in EL7, but not in EL6.

Answer (score 1):

These are not OS packages but rather modules provide for Perl, most modules can be gotten through CPAN.

Have a look [here](http://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html) for details on how to do this.  Its a fairly easy process.

Answer (score 0):

I used these commands to install these Perl modules through CPAN:

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/master/cpanm | perl - App::cpanminus
cpanm LWP::Protocol::https
cpanm Switch
cpanm Sys::Syslog
```

I used *cpanm* but I could have used *cpan* command.